# How does bulk Advertisement opt-out work? What services exist?

Tags: privacy, web-browser, cookies, user-tracking, browser-extensions

There are a few online advertisement opt-out services such as:

- http://www.aboutads.info/choices/#completed
- http://www.networkadvertising.org/choices/#completed
- http://www.youronlinechoices.com/uk/your-ad-choices

Each of those pages connect to several advertising hubs, presumably request a 3rd party cookie to determine if tracking is enabled or not. This process is repeated several times. Screenshot:

[image]

I'd like to understand this transaction, how it works for determining status at a given provider, and how the non-track attribute is maintained.

Specifically

- Does each vendor have a standard way of determining tracking? (e.g. a ./well-known/ RFC based URL?)
- Is the query to that vendor a GET or POST
- What is the return value, and header information?
- Is the return value and header information standardized in any way?
- If a cookie is set on the client, is it a unique identifier of sorts, or is it a generic "don't track me" request?

Comment: Bulk advertisement opt-out is called ad blocking. What you are showing here is called snake oil. I don't see why you should trust advertisers not to track you just because you asked nicely.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a security question at all. Seems more web and API programming.